# Using pgfplotstable inside tabular environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

Is there a way to get a table created with pgfplotstable inside another tabular environment.  I'm trying to get multiple subtables in multiple columns.  The following simplified version does not work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}    

% this works
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C\\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

% this doesn't work
\begin{tabular}{c}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
   col sep=space,
   header=false,
   columns/0/.style={int detect, column name=A},
   columns/1/.style={int detect, column name=B},
   columns/2/.style={int detect, column name=C},
]{%
1 2 3
4 5 6
}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! One thing that does work is to write the table in a savebox and then to use it in the outer table.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\newsavebox{\mytab}
\begin{document}    

% this works
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C\\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\begin{lrbox}{\mytab}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
   col sep=space,
   header=false,
   columns/0/.style={int detect, column name=A},
   columns/1/.style={int detect, column name=B},
   columns/2/.style={int detect, column name=C},
]{%
1 2 3
4 5 6
}
\end{lrbox}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\usebox{\mytab}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This work for this problem.  After a few days of tinkering, I was able to get it to work inside the environment I needed it in.